# Calculated column adding number of days based on two other columns

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I need a column that contains the "Estimated SLA Completion Date", which is calculated by "SLA" and "Date Priority Set". 
SLA can equal 3 Days, 5 Days, 10 Days, 30 Days or 60 Days.
Date Priority Set would be mm/dd/yyyy
For Example if Date Priority Set is 04/01/2015, and SLA is 3 days then Estimated SLA Completion Date would be 04/04/2015. 
I am getting hung up because the SLA actually has the word "Days" after each number. So I think I need a nested IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column and set the return type as Date only.

Add the below formula:

```
=[Date Priority Set]+LEFT([SLA],LEN([SLA])-5)
```